# When is Time.frameCount incremented?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity3D offers many per-frame callbacks, the most used being `Update`. There are also lesser-used ones like `OnWillRenderObject`, `OnRenderObject`, and `OnPostRender`. With respect to the order in which these callbacks are called, when is `Time.frameCount` incremented?

I'm trying to synchronize frame-grabs I'm capturing after rendering completes with object properties recorded from other callbacks in that frame. I found that when `OnPostRender` is called, `Time.frameCount` has already been incremented, so that the frame I'm being notified of is actually the previous frame. For this reason, I'd like to know what other callbacks are called after the frame count has been incremented.

Comment: Good question... pretty sure it is incremented before Update, and after the Physics and input events. Definitely before any Scene Rendering.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of Update as being before the increment, in that the `Time.frameCount` when `Update` is called is the "current frame". It's incremented between one `Update` and the next `Update`, but when?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote this script in order to capture when `Time.frameCount` is changed:

```c#
using UnityEngine;

public class OnFrameCounterDetector : MonoBehaviour {

    int frameNumber = 0;
    string prevMethod;

    private void Awake() {
        Time.fixedDeltaTime = 1 / 60;
        prevMethod = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void OnEnable() {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void Start () {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void Update () {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void LateUpdate() {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void OnWillRenderObject() {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void OnPreCull() {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void OnBecameVisible() {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void OnBecameInvisible() {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void OnPreRender() {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void OnRenderObject() {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void OnPostRender() {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture source, RenderTexture destination) {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos() {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void OnGUI() {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void OnApplicationPause(bool pause) {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void OnDisable() {
        CheckFrameCount(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
    }

    private void CheckFrameCount(string callback) {
        if (Time.frameCount > frameNumber) {
            Debug.LogFormat("frameCount changed between {0} and {1}", prevMethod, callback);
            frameNumber = Time.frameCount;
        }
        prevMethod = callback;
    }
}
```

Inside the editor, I got the change between `OnGUI` OR `OnRenderObject` and `FixedUpdate`, but the scene was almost empty, with just a single camera and a game object with a `Sprite Renderer` on it.

The difference was if I had the game object selected or the camera in the hierarchy, if the GO was selected, then `OnRenderObject` would be signaled, if not (i.e.: keep the camera selected in hierarchy), `OnGUI`.

You may use this script in more detailed scenes, since most of the callbacks aren't called at all in a simple scene, curious at the results.

BTW, I didn't bother to add coroutines with the various yields, they could be added though very easily to catch more "moments" in the game loop, like the one between Update and LateUpdate, etc.

Comment: `OnGUI` is not reliable since it may be called multiple times per frames.

Comment: as may `OnFixedUpdate`. But this is the kind of experiment I was hoping somebody had done!

Comment: It doesn't matter if `OnGUI` is called even 1000 times in a single frame,the script catches when `frameCount` increases and then reports between which methods that happened.

Comment: Well, that's fine for OnGUI, because all the calls happen at once, but FixedUpdate can happen at different times, "in between" frames, to keep the rate it's called constant.

Comment: No, `FixedUpdate` is called 0, 1 or up to `MaxAllowedTimestep/fixedDeltaTime` between two different `Update` callbacks, so that's not a bother either.

Answer (score -2):

According to the [Execution Order or MonoBehaviour messages](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html), I think we could assume the following functions are called after `Time.frameCount` is incremented since `Time.frameCount` represents the number of **rendered** frames :

1. `OnPostRender`
2. `OnRenderImage`
3. Coroutines which have called `yield WaitForEndOfFrame`
4. `OnApplicationPause`
5. `OnDisable` (if script has been disabled during the frame)

Comment: It's definitely incremented **after** `OnRenderImage`. I've found that through my local testing. I'm looking for an authoritative answer backed by experiment or someone who knows the source, not guesswork.

Comment: Based on my experience it is incremented before Update, which occurs before OnRenderImage. Seems to be little documentation on this, curious to see if anyone has an 'official' answer.

Comment: @DanHulme : Why don't you simply implement all the MonoBehaviour messages and check by yourself when the value of `Time.frameCount` changes if you want "an authoritative answer backed by experiment" ?

Comment: By the way, you indicated in your question that "I found that when OnPostRender is called, Time.frameCount has already been incremented", which contradicts your first comment : "It's definitely incremented **after** `OnRenderImage`"

Comment: Don't assume. Never.